# Predicciones en una serie temporal

Tags: python, timeseries

Estoy haciendo predicciones con una serie temporal y tengo este código, pero cuando hago la gráfica con las predicciones no salen con los datos de tiempo correctos. Se van hacia la derecha cuando deberían salir con las fechas del test y no sé cómo solucionar ese error.

```
Separación de los datos en train y test:(comprobé que las fechas de los steps eran las correctas y salieron bien, no pongo el código para no saturar la pregunta)--->
train= datos['2022-04-18 00:00:00':'2022-05-13 00:00:00']
test=datos['2022-05-13 00:00:00':'2022-05-14 00:00:00']
steps=len(datos['2022-05-13 00:00:00':])
datos_train= datos[:-steps]
datos_test=datos[-steps:]
Sin embargo, cuando entreno y hago las predicciones con el modelo (lo he intentado con varios) siempre me sale una gráfica como ésta.
Gráfico con las predicciones del modelo entrenado:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
En este gráfico las predicciones se van a la derecha cuando deberían salir sobre la línea de test y lo he intentado de varias maneras y con varios modelos y me sale igual, así que el error debe estar en la separación de train test pero no consigo arreglarlo.
```

Muchas gracias!